# Libsvm save model file in binary format

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am training a huge data file for libsvm and the resulting training file is too large. Is there any way to save the libsvm libraries model file in binary format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using Matlab:**
Download [svm_savemodel.c](http://buptlijun.is-programmer.com/user_files/buptlijun/File/svm_savemodel.c) and [svm_model_matlab.c](http://buptlijun.is-programmer.com/user_files/buptlijun/File/svm_model_matlab.c) (this is already included in libsvm, you can try to use the original one, but if it doesn't work, try this link) to your libsvm dir. Compile the Mex file (`mex svm_savemodel.c`), then it should work:

```
%save model model

fid = fopen('model.bin','w');
model = fwrite(fid, model, 'int16');

%load('model.mat');

fid = fopen('model.bin','rb');
model = fread(fid, model, 'int16');

svm_savemodel(model,'model.model');
```

**If you are using C++:**
There is a function that saves a model to a file:

```
int svm_save_model(const char *model_file_name, const struct svm_model *model);
```

More details are included in the [github](https://github.com/vincenzo/LIBSVM-Plus).

Comment: It stores the file in text format. I want it to store in binary format as size of file is very huge.

Comment: @Krish Matlab can write the data as binary as binary file. I don't try it on C but I guess C can do the same thing as well