# Is there a savemodel for Scikitlearn? And why is its predict limited to [-1/1]?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

When I use SVM in Scikit-learn it looks like there is no save to disk method unlike [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624343) systems?
I know the result is a list of coefficients and you could save to disk then open and dot-product it, but is there a recommended way to save and recreate the SVC?

```
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=3)
    dir(clf) #No "save" method??
```

Also, I find it odd that the SVM has a range of in or out of positive/negative grouping (-1/1 training data) and the SVM's .predict([array]) returns -1 or 1, 
but there's no reason the [dotproduct](https://github.com/rogue-hack-lab/PythonMachineLearningSVMExamples/blob/master/coffee.py) should be limited to those values, unless they are optimizing and saying anything positive result is 1, negative -1, while they are multiplying and adding the linear result? How can you see the degree to which it fits predicted classification?

Comment: You seem to setup your problem as classification and therefore predict returns the predicted classes (it's a discrete-set). Underlying values in terms of svm-theory (used for predict) are accessible through clf.decision_function (to be honest: all that is documented very well! including model-persistence)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to save the model to your disk

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'filename')
```

You can load the model as follows

```
clf = joblib.load('filename')
```